# split a group into subgroups based on value in group

Tags: powershell

I've an array that contains a list of Databases, servers and the Cluster Nodes those servers are hosted on. I want to split that group into 4 sub-groups, one for each node. How can i do this?

The plan is the to have a process run looping through each sub-group. 
This gives me the main group.

```
$Networks | %{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | out-null
    $Srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $_.DataSource 
        $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
        NetworkInternalCode = $_.NetworkInternalCode
        DataSource = $_.DataSource
        InitialCatalog = $_.InitialCatalog
        ReportingDataSource = $_.ReportingDataSource
        ReportingInitialCatalog = $_.ReportingInitialCatalog
        HostNode = $Srv.ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS
        }
}
```

That gives me an array

```
NetworkInternalCode     : coal
DataSource              : d03\dev
InitialCatalog          : devcoal
ReportingDataSource     : d03\dev
ReportingInitialCatalog : reporting_devcoal
HostNode                : SQLD03

NetworkInternalCode     : lemons
DataSource              : d02\dev
InitialCatalog          : devlemons
ReportingDataSource     : d02\dev
ReportingInitialCatalog : reporting_devlemons
HostNode                : SQLD06


NetworkInternalCode     : coal
DataSource              : d05\dev
InitialCatalog          : devoranges
ReportingDataSource     : d05\dev
ReportingInitialCatalog : reporting_devcoranges
HostNode                : SQLD07

NetworkInternalCode     : apples
DataSource              : d08\dev
InitialCatalog          : devapples
ReportingDataSource     : d08\dev
ReportingInitialCatalog : reporting_devcapples
HostNode                : SQLD09
```

When I query it, I get 4 Node names

```
$results | Select -ExpandProperty HostNode -Unique
```

```
SQLD03
SQLD06
SQLD09
SQLD07
```

Comment: Try ```$results -split "`n"```?

Comment: That's not going to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `$1, $2, $3, $4 = $results`?

Comment: the `%` [modulo or modulus] operator will give you the remainder of `$CurrentNumber % $BatchSize`. you can then use that with a `switch` command to send items to different batches. [*grin*] lookee ... >>> about_Arithmetic_Operators - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-5.1&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

You can split the variable like this

```
$1, $2, $3, $4 = $results
```

Testing:

```
$res = @()
$res += [PSCustomObject]@{
NetworkInternalCode = "coal" 
DataSource = "do3\dev"
InitialCatalog = "devcoal"
ReportingDataSource = "do3\dev"
ReportingInitialCatalog = "reporting_devcoal"
HostNode = "SQLD03"
}
$res += [PSCustomObject]@{
NetworkInternalCode = "lemons"
DataSource = "do2\dev"
InitialCatalog = "devlemons"
ReportingDataSource = "do2\dev"
ReportingInitialCatalog = "reporting_devlemons"
HostNode = "SQLD06"
}
$1, $2 = $res
```

Output

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> $1

NetworkInternalCode     : coal
DataSource              : do3\dev
InitialCatalog          : devcoal
ReportingDataSource     : do3\dev
ReportingInitialCatalog : reporting_devcoal
HostNode                : SQLD03


PS C:\Users\Neko> $2


NetworkInternalCode     : lemons
DataSource              : do2\dev
InitialCatalog          : devlemons
ReportingDataSource     : do2\dev
ReportingInitialCatalog : reporting_devlemons
HostNode                : SQLD06
```